# I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS

Tags: css

I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS.

I have one div which is the parent, and I have another div inside the first div which is the child.

I want to set the opacity property in the parent div, but I don't want the child div to inherit the opacity property.

How can I do that?

Comment: `opacity` is a a bit like `display: none` in this sense.

Comment: look at the popular http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parent div transparent background but not affect child div transparency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148128/parent-div-transparent-background-but-not-affect-child-div-transparency)

Comment: Have you tried using RGBA with transparency level instead of opacity?

Comment: Used a `class="overrideClass1"` on that specific element, with `overrideClass1 { opacity: 1 }` and it worked

Answer (score 791):

Instead of using opacity, set a background-color with rgba, where 'a' is the level of transparency.

So instead of:

```
background-color: rgb(0,0,255); opacity: 0.5;
```

use

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
```

Comment: This works for background color only, unless text color supports alpha channel? Another similar solution for background is of course the mighty `.png` :)

Comment: background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
this code is right, but does not work with ie6 and ie7

Comment: @Madmartigan Yes, if you want the text in the parent div to have opacity, then you would have to set the opacity of the text with a span. You can use a polyfill to make it backwards compatible, or you can use a png.

Comment: @LionKing - There are a few ways around it. You can build a 1x1 semi-transparent PNG, then use a conditional comment to set it as the background image on the parent div, and use AlphaImageLoader to make the transparency work.

Comment: Welcome to CSS - as far as I know there is no quicker way that is cross-browser compatible. Fortunately, once you have the code working once, you can use it across other projects. The only other option is to use jQuery's opacity function which handles a lot of this for you.

Comment: Text color supports alpha channels, sure.  `color:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)` should work in all modern browsers.

Comment: @Lion King did you find a way of doing it that you were happy with?

Comment: This is the way to do it! +1 for thinking outside the box here!

Comment: Awesome solution for font icons! You can hide plain text inside a tag while showing a pseudoelement of the same tag (though to be accessible the result still requires a separate child tag instead of a pseudo).

Comment: here is one of the link to convert hex to rgb or rgba http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/

Answer (score 76):

Opacity is not actually inherited in CSS.  It's a post-rendering group transform.  In other words, if a `<div>` has opacity set you render the div and all its kids into a temporary buffer, and then composite that whole buffer into the page with the given opacity setting.

What exactly you want to do here depends on the exact rendering you're looking for, which is not clear from the question.

Comment: In Chrome 26.0.1410.63, this is wrong. Setting `opacity: .7;` on `div#container` makes every child element — from `ul`/`li` to `img` to `p` — also have the same opacity. It is most certainly inherited.

Comment: If it were inherited, they would get lighter.  Try actually setting `opacity: 0.7` on all the descendants to see what inheritance would look like.  Like I said, what happens instead is that opacity is applied to the entire "element and all its descendants" group as a unit instead of inheriting.

Answer (score 34):

A little trick if your parent is transparent and you would like your child to be the same, but defined exclusively (e.g. to overwrite the user agent styles of a select dropdown):

```
.parent {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.child {
     background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0);
}
```

Comment: How about a gradient color?

Answer (score 31):

As others have mentioned in this and other similar threads, the best way to avoid this problem is to use RGBA/HSLA or else use a transparent PNG.

But, if you want a ridiculous solution, similar to the one linked in another answer in this thread (which is also my website), here's a brand new script I wrote that fixes this problem automatically, called thatsNotYoChild.js:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/fixing-parent-child-opacity/

Basically it uses JavaScript to remove all children from the parent div, then reposition the child elements back to where they should be without actually being children of that element anymore.

To me, this should be a last resort, but I thought it would be fun to write something that did this, if anyone wants to do this.

Answer (score 14):

Opacity of child element is inherited from the parent element.

But we can use the css position property to accomplish our achievement.

The text container div can be put outside of the parent div but with absolute positioning projecting the desired effect.

Ideal Requirement------------------>>>>>>>>>>>>

HTML

```
            <div class="container">       
              <div class="bar">
                  <div class="text">The text opacity is inherited   from the parent div    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
               .container{
                position:relative;
                                   }
           .bar{
               opacity:0.2;
               background-color:#000;
               z-index:3;
               position:absolute;
               top:0;
               left:0;
              }

              .text{
                color:#fff;

               }
```

Output:--

[image: Inherited Opacity of Text(the text color is #000; but not visisble.)]

the Text is not visible because inheriting opacity from parent div.

Solution ------------------->>>>>>

HTML

```
       <div class="container">  
         <div class="text">Opacity is not inherited from parent div "bar"</div>
         <div class="bar"></div>
       </div>
```

CSS

```
               .container{
                position:relative;
                                   }
           .bar{
               opacity:0.2;
               background-color:#000;
               z-index:3;
               position:absolute;
               top:0;
               left:0;
              }

              .text{
                color:#fff;
                z-index:3;
                position:absolute;
               top:0;
               left:0;  
               }
```

Output :

[image: Not Inherited]

the Text is visible with same color as of background because the div is not in the transparent div

Answer (score 12):

The question didn't defined if the background is a color or an image but since @Blowski have already answered for coloured backgrounds, there's a hack for images below:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.6), rgba(0,0,0,.6)), url('image.jpg');
```

This way you can manipulate the color of your opacity and even add nice gradient effects.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 630px;
  height: 420px;
  display: table;
  background: linear-gradient(
    rgba(0,0,0,.8), 
    rgba(0,0,0,.8)), 
    url('http://cdn.moviestillsdb.com/sm/35bc3c6a2b791425de6caf8b9391026e/rambo-iii.jpg');
 }

h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<h1>Question 5770341</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Works well. Or use the opposite light gradient instead of dark by `linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.8), rgba(255,255,255,.8))`. See the accepted answer [at "Set opacity of background image without affecting child elements"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41663193/).

Answer (score 5):

There is no one size fits-all approach, but one thing that I found particularly helpful is setting opacity for a div's direct children, except for the one that you want to keep fully visible. In code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
div.parent > div:not(.child1){
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

In case you have background colors/images on the parent you fix color opacity with rgba and background-image by applying alpha filters

Answer (score 4):

Answers above seems to complicated for me, so I wrote this:

```css
#kb-mask-overlay { 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
}

#kb-mask-overlay > .pop-up {
    width: 800px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: dimgray;
    margin-top: 30px; 
    margin-left: 30px;
}

span {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="kb-mask-overlay">
  <div class="pop-up">
    <span>Content of no opacity children</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae arcu nec velit pharetra consequat a quis sem. Vestibulum rutrum, ligula nec aliquam suscipit, sem justo accumsan mauris, id iaculis mauris arcu a eros. Donec sem urna, posuere id felis eget, pharetra rhoncus felis. Mauris tellus metus, rhoncus et laoreet sed, dictum nec orci. Mauris sagittis et nisl vitae aliquet. Sed vestibulum at orci ut tempor. Ut tristique vel erat sed efficitur. Vivamus vestibulum velit condimentum tristique lacinia. Sed dignissim iaculis mattis. Sed eu ligula felis. Mauris diam augue, rhoncus sed interdum nec, euismod eget urna.

Morbi sem arcu, sollicitudin ut euismod ac, iaculis id dolor. Praesent ultricies eu massa eget varius. Nunc sit amet egestas arcu. Quisque at turpis lobortis nibh semper imperdiet vitae a neque. Proin maximus laoreet luctus. Nulla vel nulla ut elit blandit consequat. Nullam tempus purus vitae luctus fringilla. Nullam sodales vel justo vitae eleifend. Suspendisse et tortor nulla. Ut pharetra, sapien non porttitor pharetra, libero augue dictum purus, dignissim vehicula ligula nulla sed purus. Cras nec dapibus dolor. Donec nulla arcu, pretium ac ipsum vel, accumsan egestas urna. Vestibulum at bibendum tortor, a consequat eros. Nunc interdum at erat nec ultrices. Sed a augue sit amet lacus sodales eleifend ut id metus. Quisque vel luctus arcu. 
 </p>
</div>
```

`kb-mask-overlay` it's your (opacity) parent, `pop-up` it's your (no opacity) children. Everything below it's rest of your site.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issues, after doing some googling I found some solutions ( 3-ways ) of this problem.
I am sharing the solutions here, you can try any of these.

Option-1:
Use a pseudo markup element before or after as the background

```
.parentContainer {
    position: relative;
}
.parentContainer:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.childContent {
    position: relative;
    color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Option-2:
Use rgba colors with alpha value instead of opacity.

```
 <div id="parentContainer" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);">
    <div id="childContent">
         Content ...
    </div>
 </div>
```

Option-3:
Use background div with absolute position one element over another.

```
<div class="parentContainer">
  <div class="childContent">
    Here is the content.
  </div>
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>


.parentContainer {
  position: relative;
}
.childContent {
  position: relative;
  color: White;
  z-index: 5;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: Black;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: option2 is more convient

Answer (score 3):

Below worked for me:

1. Changed

From:

```
opacity: 0.52;
background-color: #7c7c7c;
```

To:

```
opacity: 1 !important;
background-color: rgba(124, 124, 124, 0.52) !important;
```

2. 

To convert the `hex & opacity` to `rgba`,
use a website like http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/

Comment: Not working in the chrome.

Comment: It worked for me on Chrome. Opacity goes to children also. Background is only for element. So, may be, set opacity of parent to 1, and background for both parent & children. If it does not work, share a sample on https://codesandbox.io/ or like site so that others can see too, also may be raise another question you might get more answers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `display: block` elements do not inherit opacity from `display: inline` parents.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/andrewtibbetts/pen/VawXEw)

Maybe because it's invalid markup and the browser is secretly separating them? Because source doesn't show that happening. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!--Background opacity-->
<style>
    .container1 {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
</style>
<div class="container1">
    <div class="box1">Text</div>
</div>

<!--Before, after, z-index opacity-->
<style>
    .container2 {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .container2:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: black;
        opacity: .5;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .box2 {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }
</style>
<div class="container2">
    <div class="box2">Text</div>
</div>

<!--Outline opacity-->
<style>
    .container3 {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        outline: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        margin: 50px;
    }

    .box3 {
        position: relative;
        left: -16px;
    }
</style>
<div class="container3">
    <div class="box3">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use an image as the transparent background, you might be able to work around it using a pseudo element:

html

```
<div class="wrap"> 
   <p>I have 100% opacity</p>  
</div>
```

css

```
.wrap, .wrap > * {
  position: relative;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: " ";
  opacity: 0.2;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100/FF0000") repeat;     
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not about static parent-child layout, its about animations.

I was doing an svg demo today, and i needed svg to be inside div (because svg is created with parent's div width and height, to animate the path around), and this parent div needed to be invisible during svg path animation (and then this div was supposed to `animate opacity from 0 to 1`, it's the most important part). And because parent div with `opacity: 0` was hiding my svg, i came across this hack with `visibility` option (child with `visibility: visible` can be seen inside parent with `visibility: hidden`):

```
.main.invisible .test {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.main.opacity-zero .test {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s !important;
}
.test { // parent div
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.test-svg { // child svg
  visibility: visible;
}
```

And then, in js, you removing `.invisible` class with timeout function, adding `.opacity-zero` class, trigger layout with something like `whatever.style.top;` and removing `.opacity-zero` class.

```
var $main = $(".main");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $main.addClass('opacity-zero').removeClass("invisible");
    $(".test-svg").hide();
    $main.css("top");
    $main.removeClass("opacity-zero");
  }, 3000);
```

Better to check this demo http://codepen.io/suez/pen/54bbb2f09e8d7680da1af2faa29a0aef?editors=011

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by first creating and saving a faded image which I then used in the css background. I used the following python code:

```
from PLI import Image
bg = Image.open('im1.jpg')
fg = Image.open('im2.jpg')
#blend at ratio .3
Image.blend(bg,fg,.3).save('out.jpg')
```

Here, im1.jpg was simply a white image of the same dimensions as im2.jpg.

Answer (score -1):

**On mac** you can use *Preview* editor to apply opacity to a white rectangle laid over your .png image before you put it in your .css.
1) Image
[Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyFAA.png)
2) Create a rectangle around the image
[Rectanle around logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqWDy.png)
3) Change background color to white
[rectangle turned white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgYgu.png)
4) Adjust rectangle opacity
[opaque image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Zwd.png)

Answer (score -3):

For other people trying to make a table (or something) look focused on one row using opacity. Like @Blowski said use color not opacity. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2en6o43d/

```
.table:hover > .row:not(:hover)
```

Answer (score -3):

Assign opacity 1.0 to the child recursively with:

```
div > div { opacity: 1.0 }
```

Example:

```css
div.x { opacity: 0.5 }
div.x > div.x { opacity: 1.0 }
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #f00; padding:20px;">
  <div style="background-color: #0f0; padding:20px;">
    <div style="background-color: #00f; padding:20px;">
      <div style="background-color: #000; padding:20px; color:#fff">
         Example Text - No opacity definition
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
<div style="opacity:0.5; background-color: #f00; padding:20px;">
  <div style="opacity:0.5; background-color: #0f0; padding:20px;">
    <div style="opacity:0.5; background-color: #00f; padding:20px;">
      <div style="opacity:0.5; background-color: #000; padding:20px; color:#fff">
        Example Text - 50% opacity inherited
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="x" style="background-color: #f00; padding:20px;">
  <div class="x" style="background-color: #0f0; padding:20px;">
    <div class="x" style="background-color: #00f; padding:20px;">
      <div class="x" style="background-color: #000; padding:20px; color:#fff">
         Example Text - 50% opacity not inherited
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
<div style="opacity: 0.5; background-color: #000; padding:20px; color:#fff">
  Example Text - 50% opacity
</div>
```