# Setting an individual div opacity to 1 while parent opacity is set to .7 in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a `nav` component as shown below with four props that are all booleans used to control UI styling

```
const Nav = ({ isNav, isVisibleTwo, isVisibleThree, isVisibleFour }) => {
  return (
    <nav className={isNav ? 'bubbs bubbs-enter' : 'bubbs'}>
      <GiHamburgerMenu />
      <a href="#projects-title">
        <div className={isVisibleFour ? 'bubble bubble-active' : 'bubble'}>
          <p>{`//`} P</p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#resume-title">
        <div className={isVisibleTwo ? 'bubble bubble-active' : 'bubble'}>
          <p>{`//`} R</p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#contact-me">
        <div className={isVisibleThree ? 'bubble bubble-active' : 'bubble'}>
          <p>{`//`} C</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

`isNav` controls whether the `nav` is visible or not by toggling classes that control opacity.

`bubbs-enter` sets `opacity: 0.7`

the problem I'm having is if the `bubble-active` class is applied I want the opacity of the bubble to be set to 1. Which is not working currently because the `nav` opacity is set to .7

is there a valid work around for this?

**CSS**

```
nav {
  width: 6rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-end;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3.2rem;
  /* padding-top: 3rem; */
}

.bubbs {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

.bubbs > svg {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.bubbs-enter {
  opacity: .7;
}

.bubbs-enter:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.246)
}

.bubble {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 1px solid rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.216);
  width: 3.6rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: .5rem 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.349);
  transition: all ease 350ms;
}

.bubble:hover {
  transform: scale(1.06);
}

.bubble p {
  color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all ease 550ms;
}

.bubble-active {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transform: scale(1.06);
}

.bubble-active > p {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005047/can-a-child-div-have-a-higher-opacity-than-parent-with-css) suggests a child element can override parents opacity.

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and preferably make a runnable snippet. It is going to depend on what each element holds as to what you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is a bit complex to achieve with CSS. You may want to take a look at setting the opacity of each child element than setting the opacity of the parent.

Take a look at the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css)