# Returning the opacity of contents inside a low-opacity div

Tags: jquery, html, css, opacity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css)

My page contains the following `<div>`:

```
<div id="OffDiv">
    <asp:Image ID="imgHammer" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/hammer.png" ToolTip="Biding..." />
</div>
```

and the css :

```
div#OffDiv
{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 90000;
    background-color: Blue;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.4; /* khtml, old safari */
    -moz-opacity: 0.4; /* mozilla, netscape */
    opacity: 0.4; /* fx, safari, opera */
    text-align: center;
}
#imgHammer
{
    margin-top: 100px;
    z-index: 90001
     filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 1; /* khtml, old safari */
    -moz-opacity: 1; /* mozilla, netscape */
    opacity: 1; /* fx, safari, opera */
    z-index: 90001;
}
```

The problem is the `imgHammer` has a low opacity like `OffDiv` (meaning .4) after it is rendered.

How can I change its opacity to 1?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css

Comment: The opacity of the containing div is going to continue to affect any child elements. Either set the opacity on that div, or remove the image from the div.

Comment: ok, i want to slideUp and Down the offDiv...so if i put that img inside another div how can i synchronize both sildeUp and Down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use rgba colors (0-256 instead of 00-FF) :

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqHXB/