# Reseting opacity of child element of an element with some opacity

Tags: html, css

I do not want a child element to inherit parent opacity.
[enter link description here][1]

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/xALAW/  jsfiddle

```
<html>

    <head></head>
    <body>

        <div class='hasopacity'>
            This is the text with some opacity
            <div class='noopacity'>
                This is the text with no opacity 
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

css

```
.hasopacity{opacity:0.5}
.noopacity{opacity:1}
```

Comment: Then, as far as I know, you have to make it a sibling rather than a child.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child elements must inherit the parent's opacity setting.

The only solution that I am aware of is to have the element that normally would be the child to actually be a sibling element that is positioned to seem like it was a child element.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, this is because you're making transparent something, if another something is inside it, it will be transparent too!

Anyway, this is a repeated question: [I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css)