# How do I avoid getting a lower opacity by a div in a div?

Tags: css

If I put things with **opacity:1;** in a div with **opacity:0.5;**, the one with **opacity:1;** gets an opacity of 0.5, but I don't wan't that, but I need the outside div to be 0.5 because that is a background. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you please post your html and css?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your use-case, but you may be able to use a `background-color` with opacity:

```
background-color: #8888FF; /* fallback for browsers with no alpha-transparency support */
background-color: rgba(0,0,255, 0.5);
```

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css).

Comment: +1 for alpha transparently. Be sure to dev declare a fall back for older browsers before the rule by adding a background color with a hex value

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this,

```
<div id="divA" style="opacity:0.5">
  divA
  <div id="divB" style="opacity:1">
     divB
  </div>
</div>
```

I always do the following as the alternative:

```
<div id="superparentdiv" style="position:relative">
  <div id="divA" style="opacity:0.5">
    divA
  </div>
  <div id="divB" style="opacity:1">
     divB
  </div>
</div>
```

and if the position matters, I apply `position:absolute;` to set the position of the `divB`

Hope this helps.

Comment: got it already. I can use **background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);** as the color of the outside div.

Answer (score 0):

While tricks could be employed, what you are trying to do is not possible. The child's opacity is relative to its parent. Thus, an opacity of "1" on the child will only ever equal the full opacity of its parent (0.5).

If the parent (opacity 0.5) is just a color, you can use rgba instead of opacity. Otherwise, you'll need to remove the child from its parent and use positioning to place the child above the background.

Comment: Right! I used **background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);** as the color of the outside div.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried in the 1 opacity things to add a z-index:9999(just a big )
so hey will be at the top of the 0.5 division