# Parent Opacity affects the child image opacity

Tags: css, html, opacity

Hi all i have problem i have one parent div that has opacity of 0.7 but i have a div that has a logo image inside and parent opacity affects it please help me the code looks like this

```
<div class="banner">
    <img src="banner.png" width:100%>
    <div class="navbac">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>a href"#">Home</a></li>
            <li>a href"#">Contact</a></li>
            <li>a href"#">About us</a></li>
         </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

the css code

```
.navbac{backgroud:#FFF; opacity:0.7; position:relative;bottom:730px;}
.logo{background:url(img/logo.PNG) no-repeat; width:257px; height:50px;}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css), you have to use `rgba` opacity. If you want the text in the parent div to have opacity, then you would have to set the opacity of the text with a span

> Opacity is not actually inherited in CSS. It's a post-rendering group transform. In other words, if a  has opacity set you render the div and all its kids into a temporary buffer, and then composite that whole buffer into the page with the given opacity setting.

```
.navbac {
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    position:relative;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xfuS/1/)

Also, your HTML has multiple errors which I fixed in my jsFiddle