# Remove inheritance of opacity from parent?

Tags: css, html, inheritance, overlay, opacity

I have a `div` tag. I want to remove the children's inheritance of `#overlay`'s opacity

Here is my code:

```
<body id="bg">
    <div id="overlay">
        <header id="colortext">dgjdhgjdhd</header>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this my css code.

```
#bg{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(../Images/bg.jpg);
}
#overlay{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#colortext{
    background-image:none;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    top: 2%;
    left: 2%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: xx-large;
    opacity:1 !important;
}
```

I want to have like this site background: http://www.ehsanakbari.ir/

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'remove inherit'?

Comment: i want disable inherit from all use tag in div

Comment: I think I know what you mean. You'd want to use a child selector; `div#overlay>*` this will match only yet all immediate children of your div. Then you apply rules which reset ones from the div.

Comment: i'm sorry. my english language is very bad.but i hope i could get what i mean

Comment: my header tag have opacity 0.5  . i want to use opacity 1 in header and all other tag in <div id="overlay">

Comment: Ahh... unfortunatly, that's not so easy, I'm afraid. That's not an issue of inheritance though, per se.

Comment: can i use jquery for solve this problem?if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot stop children elements from inheriting their parent's opacity.

Instead, you could use an `rgba` value for the parent's background color instead of `opacity`:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5770341/2065702) for more info.