# Parent's transparent background is making child images transparent

Tags: html, opacity

I have set my main background to transparent, I am placing an image on top of the background it is inheriting the opacity 0.4, I don't want that. I want it to be 100%. I even tried `opacity 1.0` didn't work here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Background -->
<img src="img/bg.jpg" id="bg" alt="">

<!-- The image -->
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "logo">

      <img src="img/logo.png" width="100%" height="141" id="logo" alt="Title" /> 
      </div>
      </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
//Background
    #bg {
      position: fixed; 
      top: 0; 
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0.4; 

      width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }

//the image
#logo {
    opacity : 1.0;!important;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove inheritance of opacity from parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080235/remove-inheritance-of-opacity-from-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the opacity channel is inherited

try using the `rgba` property instead:

`background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); /* red, gree, blue, alpha (opacity) */`

**Credit:** answer adapted from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21080679/600486)

```css
#bg {
  z-index: -1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.logo,
#logo {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Background -->
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" id="bg" alt="">

<!-- The image -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/150" width="100%" height="150" id="logo" alt="Title" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, part of the issue was solved, i had later on full opacity with black background, i have to change this `.logo,
#logo {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);` to this `.logo,
#logo {
  background-color: Transparent;`

Then it worked perfectly! thank you!