# How to prevent outer <div> CSS from affecting inner <div> CSS

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have set opacity on the outer wrapper to (0.5). However, this sets all the inner elements' opacity to (0.5) also. How can I make it so that the inner elements have an opacity of 1? Thanks!

```
//..The HTML..//

<div class="nav-wrapper">

    <div class="circle1"></div>
    <div class="circle2"></div>
    <div class="circle3"></div>
    <div class="circle4"></div>
    <div class="circle5"></div>

 </div>

//..The CSS..//

.circle1 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #BBBBBB;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css)

Comment: why opacity on a white element? is there a background image? with your code there is no need for opacity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a rgba background instead of opacity for the nav-wrapper

```
.nav-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    //opacity: 0.5;
    //background: white;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the terms so I couldn't find the duplicate post.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. This is not how opacity works. Use `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);` instead. (`rgba();` is color with RGB, and opacity)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwztL6gq/)

When you give `background` and `opacity` property to parent div then it also affects to its child divs. that's why you need to use **background:rgba(red,green,blue,alpha_value)**

You can refer [here](http://thenewcode.com/239/Whats-The-Difference-Between-opacity-and-rgba)