# How to enable a button in a disabled list item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a disabled list item that contains a button that I want enabled.

The `Mui-disabled` class on the parent disabled everything all the way down.

Is there a way to override this?

[image]

Comment: Please put your relevant code here.

Comment: I added a screenshot.  Its just a button in a list disabled list item, I'm not sure what code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListItemButton` which is disabled has the `pointer-events` set to `none` so you can't click anything inside. To resolve that override your inner button again:

**V5**

```
import Button, { buttonClasses } from "@mui/material/Button";
```

```
<List
  sx={{
    [`&& .${buttonClasses.disabled}`]: {
      opacity: 1,
      // anything that's not a button inside ListItem
      [`& > :not(.${buttonClasses.root})`]: {
        opacity: (theme) => theme.palette.action.disabledOpacity
      },
      // inner button
      [`& > .${buttonClasses.root}`]: {
        pointerEvents: "auto"
      }
    }
  }}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**V4**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  list: {
    '&& .Mui-disabled': {
      opacity: 1,
      '& > :not(.MuiButton-root)': {
         opacity: theme.palette.action.disabledOpacity
      },
      '& > .MuiButton-root': {
         pointerEvents: "auto"
      },
    },
  }
}));
```

```
<List className={classes.list}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: what is  sx?  That is not a valid property for me.

Comment: @Chris I assume you're using v4? I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: Thank you, exactly.. I am on v4.  I actually came up with the same css solution based on your initial comment, thank you.

That said, the style is still that of a disabled button.  I imagine I can continue  overriding styles to achieve the appearance of an enabled button, but I'm wondering if that is the best way.

Is there a way to just remove the Mui-disabled class?

Comment: @Chris You need to reset the opacity in parent because it's applied to all descendent elements, then set the disable opacity to all children except the inner buttons. I've updated my answer and the demo for you.

Comment: I don't think I explained my goal too well...

I want the button in a disabled list item to be both functionally and visually enabled, while the list item itself remains both functionally and visually disabled. 

In your code example the button in the disabled list item is functionally enabled, but it's still appears to be disabled.

Comment: @Chris I swear to god the demo worked last week. I've fixed it again for you.

Comment: Dang you're quick.  Did you just change the code sandbox code?  The code in the comment looks the same to me

Comment: @Chris Yes I updated both the answer and the live demo. It's just some css specificity issue (add a another ampersand to double the class name to bump the style up)

Comment: Ok, there is something different about how it's working for me , maybe b/c its v4.  Even when i put opacity 1 directly on the button in dev tools, the parent's opacity is still causing it to appear disabled.

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure what's wrong, but I added the v4 Codesandbox for you to reference.

Comment: I think it's not working for me b/c my element structure is not quite the same.  My button is actually inside a ListItemText .  Your example couldn't be any more clear :)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/69408141-how-to-enable-a-button-in-a-disabled-list-item-forked-v08tf?file=/demo.js

Comment: @Chris yeah unfortunately after half an hour of playing around, I found there [is no easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5770892/9449426) to reset the `opacity` or `filter` in the children once set in the parent, so you have to reset the parent opacity, and tiptoe around and set the opacity in the children selectively. See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/69408141-how-to-enable-a-button-in-a-disabled-list-item-03mpj?file=/demo.js) demo.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to add a small tweak and get it to do what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in opacity. When I apply the "disabled" prop to the ListItem, it will apply opacity: 0.38, to the li element. So I just put

```
sx={{ opacity: disabled ? 0.38 : 1 }}
```

to each element inside except the required one. It looks like a bypass, but it works.