# Tailwind CSS group-hover - different opacities on nested layers not working

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm running in to an issue when trying to get different layers to fade different opacities. I've got the card element (in the code below) that I want to keep at the background opacity of 50, and make the text opacity 100 on hover.

Right now when hovering over the card everything stays at at opacity-50 and I can't get the text to change to opacity-100. I tried setting the card title opacity to 100, but it seems like the parent container is overriding the child opacity.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

```
    import React from "react";
    import greenBlock from "../assets/images/homeLayout/heroPhotos/1.jpg";
    import yellowBlock from "../assets/images/homeLayout/heroPhotos/2.jpg";
    import redBlock from "../assets/images/homeLayout/heroPhotos/8.jpg";
    
    const HomeHero = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <div className="grid w-full h-screen grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-3">
            <div className="group">
              <div
                className="flex items-center justify-center order-1 object-cover w-full h-screen text-black transition duration-500 ease-in-out bg-cover saturate-100 group-hover:saturate-50"
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${greenBlock})` }}
              >
                <div className="flex justify-center transition duration-500 ease-in-out opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100">
                  <div class="card w-96 bg-neutral text-neutral-content opacity-50">
                    <div class="card-body items-center text-center opacity-100">
                      <h2 class="card-title opacity-100">Title!</h2>
                      <p>We are using cookies for no reason.</p>
                      <div class="justify-end card-actions">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-ghost">Deny</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div className="group">
              <div
                className="flex items-center justify-center order-1 object-cover w-full h-screen text-black transition duration-500 ease-in-out bg-cover saturate-100 group-hover:saturate-50"
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${yellowBlock})` }}
              >
                <div className="flex justify-center transition duration-500 ease-in-out opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100">
                  <div className="block max-w-sm text-center bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg ">
                    <div className="px-6 py-3 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg">
                      <div class="p-6">
                        <h5 class="text-gray-900 text-xl font-medium mb-2">
                          Special title treatment
                        </h5>
                        <p class="text-gray-700 text-base mb-4">
                          With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
                          additional content.
                        </p>
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          class=" inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-blue-600 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-blue-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-blue-800 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                        >
                          Button
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="group">
              <div
                className="flex items-center justify-center order-1 object-cover w-full h-screen text-black transition duration-500 ease-in-out bg-cover saturate-100 group-hover:saturate-50"
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${redBlock})` }}
              >
                <div className="flex justify-center transition duration-500 ease-in-out opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100">
                  <div className="block max-w-sm text-center bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg ">
                    <div className="px-6 py-3 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg">
                      <div class="p-6">
                        <h5 class="text-gray-900 text-xl font-medium mb-2">
                          Special title treatment
                        </h5>
                        <p class="text-gray-700 text-base mb-4">
                          With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
                          additional content.
                        </p>
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          class=" inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-blue-600 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-blue-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-blue-800 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                        >
                          Button
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default HomeHero;
```

Comment: Tailwind playground for tweaking the code in the question above: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Nbpf9lz8VL

Answer (score 0):

In CSS changing the opacity of a parent element will do the same to all children. You want to **change the opacity of the background color** (or something similar).

[TailwindCSS docs link for this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#changing-the-opacity)

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is inherited from parent to child elements, but luckily there are a couple of ways to get around this. A lot of those ways are in the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css).

1. If it is a color, then the best way is to define the color with RGBA, where the last alpha channel is the opacity. This will not cascade.
2. If it is a picture, [this answer to the above question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005267/14077491) claims to fix the problem (though I have never tried this)
3. If it is text or anything else, I tend to go with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31556103/14077491) of changing the child element to a sibling element and setting its position so that it is in the correct place.