# My child div's opacity keeps inheriting from its parent. How can I stop that behavior?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I simply can't figure out why the `<div id="icon-menu">` still has the same opacity as the ancestor `<div class="box">`. As far as I know, according to CSS specificity, that shouldn't happen.

```
<div class="jumbotron">    
    <div class="box">
        <div id="icon-menu" style="opacity: 1">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            Menu
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.box {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 60px;
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#icon-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

As you can see, I tried some ways to change the opacity of the `<div id="icon-menu:>` back to 1, but nothing has an effect. Do you have a clue what's wrong?

Comment: A child cannot be more opaque than its parent

Comment: Children are affected by a parent's opacity. Possible duplicate of [Parent div transparent background but not affect child div transparency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148128/parent-div-transparent-background-but-not-affect-child-div-transparency)

Comment: possible duplicate of [I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can't use opacity to make a descendant element more opaque than the parent, you can use rgba coloring to do what you want:

```
.box {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    height: 60px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
#icon-menu {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    padding-left: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/55583jg4/)**

Answer (score 4):

You cannot override opacity in child elements. From MDN:

> The value applies to the element as a whole, including its contents,
>   even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, an
>   element and its contained children all have the same opacity relative
>   to the element's background, even if the element and its children have
>   different opacities relative to one another.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Answer (score 0):

It's because `#icon-menu` is inside `.box`, and the opacity applies to all children. This isn't a CSS specificity issue, but rather the way that opacity is applied.